# Guide for using Juju in deploying to a Raspberry Pi

Tags: juju, arm, raspberrypi

Where is a small-c canonical guide located for using Juju to deploy services to a Raspberry Pi or similar ARM board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the closest that comes to this is [manual provisioning](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/config-manual.html) which is noted in the documentation as being experimental at the moment.  LXC is [an available option](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/config-local.html) as well but that requires further assessment.